# Watir open javascript onclick link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, watir

I want to follow a link specified on the target page, the problem is that the link is embeeded on a `detail_open` onclick javascript function like this:

```
<tr class="odd highlight" onclick="detail_open('g_0_SzK23oET', null, null, null, '2016-2017', false)">...</tr>
```

I have tried `browser1.table(:class => 'head_to_head h2h_mutual').trs[3].fire_event :click` but without success

Also tried simply `browser1.table(:class => 'head_to_head h2h_mutual').trs[3].click`but nothing happens

**EDIT:**

This is the actual URL:
link = "http://www.flashscore.com/match/2TYx9kph/#h2h;overall"

I want to click on the links in rows of table with class `head_to_head h2h_mutual`

Comment: Are you sure that `browser.tr` is returning the right `tr` element? `browser.tr` returns the first one on the page. It would also help if you try different browsers as it's possible that it is a driver specific problem.

Comment: Have you tried a regular click on the TR? That should just work.

Comment: @JustinKo that is to simplify, in fact this is the request ``browser1.table(:class => 'head_to_head h2h_mutual').trs[3].fire_event :click``

Comment: @JeffC ``browser1.table(:class => 'head_to_head h2h_mutual').trs[3].click`` also doesn't work, if I call ``browser1``after request, returns the same URL

Comment: Is there an error or does it silently fail?  And you should directly edit your question (instead of posting code in the comments) so that it's easier to read.

Comment: @orde it's done, from what I see it's not returning any error.. but not sure if that's failing or simply not following the link because it isn't meant to go to the link with that command

Comment: @orde it simply returns true ``irb(main):284:0> browser1.table(:class => 'head_to_head h2h_mutual').trs[3].fire_event :click
=> true``

Comment: Hmmm...don't want to just take shots in the dark.  If you could post the whole table (or even better a link to the actual site), it'll make it easier for people to help.

Comment: @orde understandable! I have updated the initial posting

Comment: I think the problem is that it isnt actually a link but a redirection inside the page

Comment: If your goal is to launch the game-specific popup, your `watir` snippets work for me using `watir (6.0.2)` + chrome 55.  You may want to edit your question to include more environmental data (e.g. OS, browser w/ version,   `watir` version, if you are really using PhantomJS, etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134045/discussion-between-ace-and-orde).

Comment: @orde I'm using phantomjs, maybe it's also working for me but since it opens in a new popup it may just be noobness by me. After the request my ``browser1``is still the original URL, may I look for anything else? If yes what's the command to check the new open tab?

Comment: Thank you. needed to change the tab

Answer (score 0):

Dumb me..
Just needed to change to the new opened tab:

```
browser1.windows.last.use
```